# Opencl application does not recognize GPU till user physically ( and not remote) logs in to machine

Tags: drivers, ati, ssh, lightdm, opencl

I run some opencl applications on 2x AMD Radeon HD 7870 on a machine running Ubuntu 13.10.

I power the machine on and lightdm has the login prompt. Since I cannot physically be present to login to the machine everytime I power cycle it. I want to troubleshoot why Opencl does not detect the GPU following a power cycle on the machine.

Without logging in in lightdm , if I ssh into the machine and start the opencl jobs.
Opencl does not "see" the GPU.

Only If I login to the machine by being physically present and logging into lightdmdoes the remote shell "see" the GPU.

I dont know much about openCL to provide more information, but this seems to be something about how ubuntu initializes. What does logging in to the lightdm console ..do to the state of the graphics driver.

Is there some way to "load" the driver to have OpenCL see it.

Strangely lsmod shows "fglrx" loaded and in use when Opencl fails to "see" the GPU.

#

State without loggin into lightdm and as reported by a ssh session

#

```
   hari@hjubuntu:~$ ~/oepncl-program

    Available device list:
    Type: CPU, 'Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad  CPU   Q9450  @ 2.66GHz'


hari@hjubuntu:~$ lsmod
    Module                  Size  Used by
    pci_stub               12622  1 
    vboxpci                23194  0 
    vboxnetadp             25670  0 
    vboxnetflt             27613  0 
    vboxdrv               320455  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
    cuse                   13274  3 
    dm_crypt               22832  0 
    kvm_intel             138567  0 
    kvm                   431754  1 kvm_intel
    gpio_ich               13476  0 
    ppdev                  17671  0 
    snd_usb_audio         149162  2 
    bnep                   19704  2 
    snd_usbmidi_lib        25070  1 snd_usb_audio
    rfcomm                 69130  0 
    bluetooth             372041  10 bnep,rfcomm
    snd_hda_codec_hdmi     41154  2 
    microcode              23656  0 
    psmouse                97655  0 
    snd_hda_codec_realtek    56475  1 
    serio_raw              13413  0 
    snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
    snd_hda_intel          52267  7 
    snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
    snd_hda_codec         188738  3 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
    snd_rawmidi            30095  2 snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_seq_midi
    snd_hwdep              13602  2 snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec
    lpc_ich                21080  0 
    snd_pcm               102033  4 snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
    snd_seq                61560  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
    snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
    snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
    snd_timer              29433  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
    fglrx                8815330  48 
    snd                    69141  31 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_usb_audio,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
    it87                   43113  0 
    hwmon_vid              12783  1 it87
    parport_pc             32701  1 
    coretemp               13435  0 
    x38_edac               12898  0 
    soundcore              12680  1 snd
    lp                     17759  0 
    parport                42299  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
    binfmt_misc            17468  1 
    mac_hid                13205  0 
    amd_iommu_v2           19054  1 fglrx
    edac_core              62342  1 x38_edac
    vesafb                 13828  1 
    pata_acpi              13038  0 
    hid_generic            12548  0 
    usbhid                 53014  0 
    hid                   101762  2 hid_generic,usbhid
    firewire_ohci          40327  0 
    firewire_core          64534  1 firewire_ohci
    crc_itu_t              12707  1 firewire_core
    r8169                  67581  0 
    mii                    13934  1 r8169
    pata_jmicron           12758  0 
    ahci                   25819  0 
    libahci                32009  1 ahci
    floppy                 69370  0
```

After the user logs in and I run the same program.

#

State after loggin in to lightdm and starting the desktop environment

#

```
hari@hjubuntu:~$ ~/opencl-program
Available device list:
Type: CPU, 'Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad  CPU   Q9450  @ 2.66GHz'
Type: GPU, 'Pitcairn'
Type: ACCELERATOR, 'Pitcairn'
```

Now If I do a diff of the lsmod
What I get is

```
hari@hjubuntu:~$ diff before_login after_login | grep fglrx
<     fglrx                8815330  48 
<     amd_iommu_v2           19054  1 fglrx
> fglrx                8815330  44 
> amd_iommu_v2           19054  1 fglrx
```

SO logging in caused the fglrx driver to get used by "44". How do I mimic this so I got have to log in when someone remote-power cycles this machine?.

edit: I am trying to implement the script below and always get a

```
"hari@hjubuntu:~$ xauth extract "$DISPLAY"
xauth: (argv):1:  bad "extract" command line"
```

The $DISPLAY environment label is blank

```
hari@hjubuntu:~$ echo $DISPLAY
```

xauth list gives

```
hjubuntu/unix:1  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  8562e9f6ac976f310d1425aa11e74184
hjubuntu:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  80f5f4c28e7e2d0fc9444b1862f5cbcb
hjubuntu:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  80f5f4c28e7e2d0fc9444b1862f5cbcb
hjubuntu/unix:13  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  142c11b5689f4bd2776e860b9d8719dd
hjubuntu/unix:14  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  08353f652f21b479a6da3a60282bce31
hjubuntu/unix:15  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  655d074dfb395f536283e70a9494428c
hjubuntu/unix:12  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  91387509c2dff960e295fdd0eb0ada52
hjubuntu/unix:11  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  914c7988660149b90eed958066ed2e71
hjubuntu/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  0ab65dbaf838a08bd8c9141fb5da7c35
```

Wondering how I should proceed.

Comment: Maybe it requires X server to be running

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often some features of the hardware are not initialised until they are needed - e.g. extra display ports etc, so it is likely in this case that actually running something which uses the relevant hardware on the card is needed to turn it on.

The cheapest/simplest way to do this is to turn on the Auto-login feature (Settings>User Accounts). It won't matter what account you do this from, so you could even use a guest account if you are worried about security.

If that is not enough (there may be permissions problems), you can share the xauthority. Just add something like this to the end of your lightdm script:

```
xauth extract /tmp/auth-file "$DISPLAY"
chmod 660 /tmp/auth-file
chgrp users /tmp/auth-file
cat > /tmp/gpuenable <<EOF
export COMPUTE=$DISPLAY
unset DISPLAY
export XAUTHORITY=/tmp/auth-file
EOF
```

then when you login remotely you just need to run `/tmp/gpuenable` before any OpenCL code. Change the group name "users" to any group you want to have access.

P.S. this isn't Ubuntu-specific, or really, even Linux specific, it is just that most other OSes have the display running all the time.

Comment: Hi I tried your approach, however I ran into a slight snag. The $DISPLAY environment variable in my case is blank and the first command fails to extract the auth-file.

Comment: I missed the deadline and wanted to award you the bounty..since I solved the problem by enabling auto login as you suggested..any idea how to award the bounty after expiration

Comment: This approximate approach resolved a similar issue for me - who would have thought that logging into a remote terminal and running a command line programme would require communication with an X Server :)

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this issue with an AMD and fglrx-update driver on Ubuntu 14.04. I could eventually use my OpenCL program after killing X.

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

Answer (score 0):

Try login with Trusted X11 forwardings:

```
ssh -Y user@machine
```

Comment: This does not seem to solve the problem. So far only the autologin user has the effect of exposing the gpu to remote shell opencl processes...although I suspect that there is something weird in the opencl code that detects the available devices. I dont see too much of a run time difference whether or not the opencl code "sees" the GPU, so I suspect it just pretends to not "see" it but runs just as fast.

Comment: @harijay, I'm not familiar with opencl. I have nvidia. If you are using kind of standard/open opencl lib's could you include a simple test program that I can compile to test.